# how to minimize using statements on sql db connection commands from C# helper class

Tags: c#, dapper

Currently, I keep writing the below code every time I have a simple select statement in my c# helper page.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBContext())
    {
        using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
```

I figured out a cleaner way to write this for update, but can't get it to work with select.
Here is what I did for update:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBContext())
  {
   await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"UPDATE PO SET ESD = @ESD WHERE PoNumber = @PoNumber",new SqlParameter("ESD", (object)ESD ?? DBNull.Value), new SqlParameter("PoNumber", PoNumber));}
   }
```

and this is what I am trying for Select, but it isn't working

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBContext())
        {
            string sqlQuery ="SELECT * FROM POStages WHERE PoNumber = @PoNumber";
           poStages =  await ctx.Database.SqlQuery((sqlQuery
                ,new SqlParameter("PoNumber", PoNumber)).ToListAsync(); 
        }
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a helpful problem description. What *happens*? Do you get a compilation error? A runtime error? Different results to what you expected? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlParameter should be @PoNumber.

Here is correct syntax, both are valid

```
await ctx.Database.SqlQuery(
    typeof(DAL.Models.POStages),
    sqlQuery, 
    new SqlParameter("@PoNumber", PoNumber)).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DAL.Models.POStages>(            
        sqlQuery, 
        new SqlParameter("@PoNumber", PoNumber)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @DinaDee actually, he did.